# Hibernate DataIntegrityViolationException of Foreign Key Violation Doesn't Let to DELETE

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, data-integrity

I have a relationship like that. There is a `Car` table and `CarGroup` table. Car group table holds cars inside it. I want that: When a car removed, if it is inside a car group it should be removed from there too as usual. I use Spring and Hibernate (I have a PostgreSQL database under it) at my project. When I want to remove a car I get that error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not delete: [com.aaa.bbb.ccc.Car#2]; SQL [delete from Car where a_id=? and st=?]; constraint [fkbc80f56cb1ece7b8]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [com.aaa.bbb.ccc.Car#2]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:582)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

I can not even delete a car from pgadmin (postgresql console) as usual. When I write that:

```
delete from Car where a_id=2 and st=2;
```

Error that I get as follows:

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "car" violates foreign key constraint "fkac80f56cb1ece7b8" on table "cargroup_car"
DETAIL:  Key (a_id)=(2) is still referenced from table "cargroup_car".

********** Error **********

ERROR: update or delete on table "car" violates foreign key constraint "fkac80f56cb1ece7b8" on table "cargroup_car"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (a_id)=(2) is still referenced from table "cargroup_car".
```

Code part from my `CarGroup` class:

```
 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "cargroup_car", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ADID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AID"))
    private Set<Car> cars;
```

**EDIT:** I want that: when I remove a car, I want it to be deleted even it is under a car group. I don't want to delete a car group to delete a car. How can I change Java side database setup(Cascade types or changing many to many into many to one and one to many etc.) to do it?

**PS:** I didn't write the Java side code. If you explain it you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the car because a row in the `cargroup_car` table has a reference to it.  So you need to delete the cargroup_car row before you delete the car.

Comment: thanks. My problem is how can I configure the Java side to do it. I mean there will be no need to delete car group to delete car. What can I do with relationship writes top of the car variable definition?

Comment: what do you mean?  You have to delete the cargroup.  Your database is set up that way.

Comment: I want to change my database setup from my Java code. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that none of the CarGroups has the car you want to delete in its set of cars:

```
public void deleteCar(Car car) {
    for (CarGroup group : car.getCarGroups()) {
        group.getCars().remove(car);
    }
    session.delete(car);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However can I do it if I change Cascade types or change many to many relationship into many to one and one to many relationships?

Comment: With cascades, AFIK, no. With two associations: yes. But I wouldn't. It would make everything else more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Just a  guess: try to add [CascadeType.REMOVE](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html#REMOVE)

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = 
  {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, 
  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Or there is an other option: you can alter the foreign key constraint in the database to cascade deletes from car to cargroup, although it may be dangerous to do so, it depends on your business logic.

Comment: thanks but I still get same error when I use `CascadeType.REMOVE`.